# Area51: Users should receive reputation for following through with a commitment

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, area-51, commitment-phase

According to http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq, there's a reputation bonus for a referred user following through with a commitment, but there's no bonus for following through with the commitment yourself. It would make sense to receive a bonus for following through yourself, to encourage actually following through. Similarly, it may make sense to have a penalty for not following through with the commitment.

Comment: I don't know that a penalty is needed, but it certainly would be good to recognize those who honour their commitments.

Comment: How about a badge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been implemented. As [the FAQ now states](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), you get 50 reputation when you fulfill your own commitment, and 25 reputation when a user you referred fulfills theirs.

Comment: Is it retroactive? I fulfilled a commitment a while back and I got nothing... NOTHING! (also, does it get affected by the cap?)

Comment: It's unaffected by the cap. It looks like you received your +50 bonus: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/recent/38?startdate=2010-07-14&enddate=2010-07-15&tab=reputation

Comment: oh, I thought this was something new and I was looking at the rep for today, thanks and sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with a penalty:  what happens if the site turns out not to be what you expect?  After all, what's happened is that some sample questions have been argued on, and then nothing happens for some time while people you don't get to know join.  Once the private beta starts, it might be functionally a different site.

Comment: +1 , one of my commitments was _painful_ to satisfy.

Answer (score 2):

There are badges (ie upholder, adherent) to be earned through following through though.